# Git pull error "unable to update local ref" how to fix this?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

This is the error message :

```
 error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': unable to resolve reference 'refs/remotes/origin/master': reference broken
    From https://bitbucket.org/abc/abc
     ! [new branch]        master     -> origin/master  (unable to update local ref)
```

when I try to pull then it shows "Complete with errors, see above", I forgot what I did before so it result this error came up after I do pull request. What should I do ?

Comment: The error basically means that there are multiple `git` processes running on your machine.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It sounds like your ref to the origin/master branch is broken or corrupt.

First - take a copy of your local repo.

You can do two things (that I know of):

1. Delete the ref to master and then do a fetch (to get the latest):

   `cd <path-to-your-repo>
   rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
   git fetch`
2. Try using the git maintenance features:

   - `git gc --prune=now`
   - `git remote prune origin` (may not need this which removes stale remote tracking branches and such)

**Note:** One reason to backup before you do this is that the git gc pruning permanently removes some commits that are un-reachable - which, in theory, you might need incase you made a mistake.

Comment: Please note: I ran into this issue as well, and the above only helped once I'd updated my `git` to the latest version. So if you're still having trouble after trying the above, ensure your `git` is updated.

Comment: @JaredH was it just the second method that was not working in the older version - or both?

Comment: Sorry but I don't recall @code_fodder

Comment: @JaredH ah, no worries : )

Comment: The second method worked for me. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: The `git remote prune origin` were the magic words in my case. Thnx!